# Temperature Conversion, without calling Methods

Tags: python-3.x, class, oop, methods, printing

I'm looking for a solution to print out t1, converted to kelvins, without calling any of the methods below. See Bottom for how t1 is created and what the solution to the print out is supposed to be. I hope to hear some feedback soon!

```
class Temperature:
    # --- YOUR CODE STARTS HERE
    val = 0


    def __init__(self,val, unit):
        self.val = val
        self.unit = unit

    def celcius(self):
        if self.unit == "F":
            new_temp = (self.val - 32)*(5/9)
            self.unit = "F"
            new_unit = self.unit
            return round(new_temp,2), new_unit
        elif self.unit == "K":
            new_temp = self.val - 273.15
            self.unit = "F"
            new_unit = self.unit
            return round(new_temp,2), new_unit
        else:
            return round(self.val,2), self.unit


    def fahrenheit(self):
        if self.unit == "C":
            new_temp = (self.val * (9/5)) + 32
            self.unit = "F"
            new_unit = self.unit
            return round(new_temp,2), new_unit
        elif self.unit == "K":
            new_temp = (val - 273.15) * (9/5) + 32
            self.unit = "F"
            new_unit = self.unit
            return round(new_temp,2), new_unit
        else:
            return round(self.val,2), self.unit

    def kelvin(self):
        if self.unit == "F":
            new_temp = (self.val - 32)*(5/9) + 273.15
            self.unit = "K"
            new_unit = self.unit
            return round(new_temp,2), new_unit
        elif self.unit == "C":
            new_temp = self.val + 273.15
            self.unit = "K"
            new_unit = self.unit
            return round(new_temp,2), new_unit
        else:
            return round(self.val,2), self.unit

    def __str__(self):





t1 = Temperature(31, "F")

print(t1)
```

The issue is printing t1 to get the result of 272.59 K

Answer (score 0):

Here's what i could do to address your requirement:

```
class Temperature:
    # --- YOUR CODE STARTS HERE
    val = 0


    def __init__(self,val, unit):
        self.val = val
        self.unit = unit

    def celcius(self):
        if self.unit == "F":
            new_temp = (self.val - 32)*(5/9)
            self.unit = "F"
            new_unit = self.unit
            return round(new_temp,2), new_unit
        elif self.unit == "K":
            new_temp = self.val - 273.15
            self.unit = "F"
            new_unit = self.unit
            return round(new_temp,2), new_unit
        else:
            return round(self.val,2), self.unit


    def fahrenheit(self):
        if self.unit == "C":
            new_temp = (self.val * (9/5)) + 32
            self.unit = "F"
            new_unit = self.unit
            return round(new_temp,2), new_unit
        elif self.unit == "K":
            new_temp = (val - 273.15) * (9/5) + 32
            self.unit = "F"
            new_unit = self.unit
            return round(new_temp,2), new_unit
        else:
            return round(self.val,2), self.unit

    def kelvin(self):
        if self.unit == "F":
            new_temp = (self.val - 32)*(5/9) + 273.15
            self.unit = "K"
            new_unit = self.unit
            return round(new_temp,2), new_unit
        elif self.unit == "C":
            new_temp = self.val + 273.15
            self.unit = "K"
            new_unit = self.unit
            return round(new_temp,2), new_unit
        else:
            return round(self.val,2), self.unit

    def __str__(self):
        self.val,self.unit = self.kelvin()
        return str(self.val) + ' ' + str(self.unit)


t1 = Temperature(31, "F")

print(t1)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to implement __str__ method.
It is like Java's toString()

This will do the trick:

```
def __str__(self):
    return "%f %s"%(self.val,self.unit)
```